# MutableLiveData doesn't apply change

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    private var number = MutableLiveData(0)

    fun addOne(){
          number.value?.let { it + 1 }
    }
```

I would like to increase my mutableLiveData by 1 all the time using my function.
But it still shows 0. What could be wrong there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not change live data value ...you are just get the value :
you should

```
number.value = number.value!! + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to update the value of mutableLiveData
1st is via postValue, if you want to update from background thread

```
fun addOne(){
    number.postValue(number.value!! + 1)
}
```

2nd is via setValue, if you want to update from main thread

```
fun addOne(){
        number.value = number.value!! + 1
    }
```